# How to compute $\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{x\bigl(\sqrt{3e^x+e^{3x^2}}-2\bigr)}{4-(\cos x+1)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a problem with this limit, I don't know what method to use. I have no idea how to compute it. Is it possible to compute this limit with the McLaurin expansion? Can you explain the method and the steps used? Thanks. (I prefer to avoid to use L'Hospital's rule.)

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{x\bigl(\sqrt{3e^x+e^{3x^2}}-2\bigr)}{4-(\cos x+1)^2}$$

Comment: *Hint:* for $x \rightarrow 0$ you have: <br/> $e^x = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + o(x^3)$, $e^{3x^2} = 1 + 3x^2 + o(x^4)$, $\cos(x) = 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + o(x^4)$. Replace those expressions in the limit and do the math: you should find the result easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** do you know about [Maclaurin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)?

You can write
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x\left(\sqrt{3e^x+e^{3x^2}}-2\right)}{4-\left(\cos x+1\right)^2}\right) = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x\left(\sqrt{3 \cdot (1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^2)) +(1 + 3x^2 + O(3x^2))}-2\right)}{4-\left((1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^2))+1\right)^2}\right) = \lim _{x\to 0} \frac{\frac34 x^2 + \frac{63}{64} x^3 + O(x^3)}{2x^2-\frac{5}{12}x^4 + O(x^6)} = \lim _{x\to 0} \frac{\frac34 x^2 + O(x^2)}{2x^2 + O(x^2)} = \frac{\frac34}{2}\\ = \frac38$$

Comment: what about the $\sqrt{}$

Comment: i've already counted in $\frac34 x^2 + \frac{63}{64} x^3 + O(x^3)$

Comment: so you have developed even $\sqrt{}$  with McLaurin?

Comment: yup! the $\sqrt{}$ it' already in $\frac34 x^2 + \frac{63}{64} x^3 + O(x^3)$

Comment: i'm sorry i don't get the method for the $\sqrt{}$ can you please write it?

Comment: the McLaurin series for $\sqrt{x}$ is $1 + \binom{\frac12}{1} x + \binom{\frac12}{1} x^2 + \ldots + O(x^n)$

Comment: The formula is this: $(1+x)^a = 1+ax+(a(a-1)x^2)/2...$. But i don't understand how to bring to this: $(1+x)^a$ what is my x in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33994/discussion-between-foga-and-amarildo).

Answer (score 3):

Let's use the elementary techniques to solve the simple limit
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(\sqrt{3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}} - 2)}{4 - (1 + \cos x)^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(\sqrt{3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}} - 2)}{4 - 4\cos^{4}(x/2)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(\sqrt{3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}} - 2)}{1 - \cos^{4}(x/2)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos(x/2)}{1 - \cos^{4}(x/2)}\cdot\frac{x(\sqrt{3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}} - 2)}{1 - \cos(x/2)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{t - 1}{t^{4} - 1}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(\sqrt{3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}} - 2)}{1 - \cos(x/2)}\text{ (putting }t = \cos(x/2))\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{16}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(\sqrt{3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}} - 2)}{1 - \cos(x/2)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{16}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(x/2)^{2}}{1 - \cos(x/2)}\frac{x(\sqrt{3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}} - 2)}{(x/2)^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}} - 2}{x}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}) - 4}{x(\sqrt{3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}} + 2)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{8}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(3e^{x} + e^{3x^{2}}) - 4}{x}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{8}\left(3\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x} - 1}{x} + \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{3x^{2}} - 1}{3x^{2}}\cdot 3x\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{8}(3\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 3\cdot 0)\notag\\
&= \frac{3}{8}\notag
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

To give another approach:

You can compute it by splitting it up:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x\left(\sqrt{3e^x+e^{3x^2}}-2\right)}{4-(1+\cos(x))^2}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3e^x+e^{3x^2}}-2}{x}\right)\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x^2}{4-(1+\cos(x))^2}\right)
$$
If you define $f(x)=\sqrt{3e^x+e^{3x^2}}$ and use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$ (you can show this using maclaurin), this gives:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x\left(\sqrt{3e^x+e^{3x^2}}-2\right)}{4-(1+\cos(x))^2}\right)=f'(0)\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\right)\left(3+\cos(x)\right)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}f'(0)
$$
It remains to calculate $f'(0)$ which is easy using the chain rule.

Comment: $(1-\cos x)/x^2 = \sin^2 x/(1+\cos x)$ so no need for McClaurin

Comment: @zhw or perhaps even faster, $$1-\cos x=2\sin^2(x/2)$$

Comment: I just wanted to show a possible approach related to the methods the OP might know.